# how to get ids of all fields inside a specified form?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I've a form with `id="myform"` - how to get ids of all inputs inside this form?

Comment: WHy did people vote to close this, seems like a straight forward question that needs no more details. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the built in elements array:

```
var f = document.getElementById('myform');
for(var i=0;i<f.elements.length;i++){
    alert(f.elements[i].id);
}
```

Elements is an array you can loop through.

Comment: Yes but substitute ".id" for ".name" to show the "id" values :-)

Comment: I just changed it to id from name, sorry.

Comment: Yet another frequently overlooked HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the form with `getElementById`, then you can get the inputs with `getElementsByTagName`. Loop over that and check the `id` property of each.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery for this purpose like this...

```
$(function(){
    var ids = $('#myform > input').map(function() { return $(this).prop('id');});
alert(ids[1]);
});
```